# Objects switching between variables in Java

Tags: java, object, geometry

I'm doing a bit of training in Java and I am stuck on how to go about this problem. How do I access the different variables? For example, I want to access `c1`'s `x` but it gives me `0`, which is the default `x`.

Here is the code:

```
class Circle {
    static double x; // x-coordinate of centre
    static double y; // y-coordinate of centre
    static double r; // radius

    static Circle c1;{
        c1.x = 1;
        c1.y= 2;
        c1.r= 4;

        double distance = Math.sqrt((x-0)*(x-0) + (y-0)*(y-0)); 
        System.out.println(distance + " " + Math.sqrt((x-0)*(x-0) + (y-0)*(y-0)) );

    }
    static Circle c2;{
        c2.x = -2;
        c2.y=0;
        c2.r=2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double distance = Math.sqrt((c1.x-0)*(c1.x-0) + (c1.y-0)*(c1.y-0)); 
        System.out.println(distance + " " + Math.sqrt((x-0)*(x-0) + (y-0)*(y-0)) );
    }
}
```

Comment: "class Circle { static double x; // x-coordinate of centre static double y; // y-coordinate of centre static double r; // radius" will not convert to code

Comment: This doesn't throw a null reference exception?

Comment: Any reason to use Static here?

Comment: You are setting values of static class variables.

Comment: It does not throw a null reference exception and I used static values because it won't access the x at all without it. how ever instead it uses 0 instead of c1.x or c2.x

Comment: You should not put brackets after variable declarations: `static Circle c1;` with no brackets. Those brackets are being used as initialization blocks; not as scopes for those specific variables. You need to initialize your variables with objects by doing `c1 = new Circle()`. You can then set the state of that object using that variable. Also, `double x` shouldnt be static, or else all circles will share the same `x` value. Tons of problems here :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating any instance of a Circle, and all your variables a static, so `x == c1.x == c2.x` (they all refer to the exact same variable).

I would get rid of the static variables and initialize the instances properly :

```
public class Circle 
{
    double x; // x-coordinate of centre
    double y; // y-coordinate of centre
    double r; // radius

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Circle c1 = new Circle();
        c1.x = 1;
        c1.y= 2;
        c1.r= 4;

        Circle c2 = new Circle ();
        c2.x = -2;
        c2.y=0;
        c2.r=2;

        System.out.println("distance " + Math.sqrt((c2.x-c1.x)*(c2.x-c1.x) + (c2.y-c1.y)*(c2.y-c1.y)) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn OOP. You need to remove static definition and add an instance method to calculate distance to other Circle. This adding is more OOP orientated.

**Here is modified code:**

```
public class Circle {

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double r;

    public Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Circle other) {
        double deltaX = other.x - this.x;
        double deltaY = other.y - this.y;

        return Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(10, 10, 10);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(100, 100, 10);   
        System.out.println(c1.distanceTo(c2));

    }
}
```